# Using Java Pattern and Matcher to search for patterns that include punctuation like forward slashes

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string like this: `1/80% of all goods sold for $44 million dollars or more/90/55`
so basically I would have a string with pattern:

> "some number" "forward slash" "some text with any punctuation including a forward slash" "forward slash" "some number" "forward slash" "some number"

I can't just use a stringtokenizer and tokenize on forward slashes because my text block could have forward slashes in it. I am very new to using patterns and matchers in java. Any clues on how I can do this? Or tutorials that might be useful? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Design-pattern? I will retag your question.

Comment: So the separators are the first slash and the last two slashes, and any other slashes are part of the text?

Comment: Pattern and Mather are parts or Regular Expression (regex) mechanism in Java. You can find more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should do it:

```
^(\d+)\/(.*?)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$
```

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ZIhe8iE0L0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work as a regex:

```
^\d+/.*/\d+/\d+$
```

Add capture groups as needed. This should work as long as the text does not contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for #/#<text>/#/#

Here's some code that should work:

```
    String toScan = "Did you know that 1/80 of all goods sold for $44 million or more/90/55? It's cool, because 1/5 of all people can type /1/2 like that.";
    String regexp = "[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}.{1,}?/[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(toScan);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class RTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test1 = "1/80% of all goods sold for $44 million dollars or more/90/55";
    String test2 = "1/80% of all goods sold for $44 /million dollars or more/90/55";

    String patternStr = "(.*?)/(.*)/(.*?)/(.*?)$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

    System.out.println("Test1...");
    // Test 1
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test1);
    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

    if (matchFound)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Test2...");
    // Test 2
    matcher = pattern.matcher(test2);
    matchFound = matcher.find();

    if (matchFound)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }       
}
```

}